# Constructive proof for existence of integer part of real number

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning, alternative-proof, cauchy-sequences

I try to prove de following exercise of my analysis textbook.

> Show that for every real number $x$ there is exactly one integer $N$ such that $N \le x < N + 1$.

I have been finding a constructive proof by Cauchy sequence definition and the lemma of integer part for rational: for every *rational* number $x$ there is exactly one integer $N$ such that $N \le x < N + 1$. So if $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence then exists a integer $N_i$ such that $N_i \le a_i < N_i + 1$ for all $i \ge 1$.

Comment: I don't believe there is a constructive proof of this. Why do you suspect there is one?

Comment: I was reading about the construction of reals by Cauchy sequences and I thought it might be a constructive proof.

Comment: Consider the set $S=\{x-n \mid x \geq n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. We take the smallest non-negative element of $S$. Such an element exists due to the unboundedness of the set $\mathbb{N}$. Let it be denoted as $(x-n_0)$. Now we prove that $0\leq (x-n_0) <1$. For suppose that $(x-n_0)\geq 1$ then notice that the number $x-(n_0+1) \in S$ because it is also non-negative and since $x-n_0>x-(n_0+1) \geq 0$ we arrive at a contradiction on the minimality of $x-n_0$. We denote this $n_0$ as $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

The unfortunate fact is that *the result in question cannot be proved constructively*.

Here "constructive proof" as usual means "a proof using the methods that are acceptable in mathematical constructivism".

If this result could be prove constructively, then we would have a constructive proof that there is a total function $f(x) = N$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, where $N$ is the unique integer with $N \leq x < N+1$. But that function is discontinuous, and any function from the real line that we can form constructively will be continuous.

In fact, any function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, which we can prove constructively is a function, must be constant. See the section 'The continuum' in [this Stanford Encyclopedia entry](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/).

It may be easier to think of the following issue, which is the root cause of the facts above. Suppose that we have a quickly-converging Cauchy sequence of rationals, $(a_n)$, that converges to a real $x$. We want to read off $f(x)$ by looking at the entries of $(a_n)$. Suppose that we see $a_k = 1-2^k$ for all the vales of $k$ we have examined. Then the sequence $(a_n)$ might continue its pattern forever, converging to $1$. Or, perhaps, at some moment, the sequence $(a_n)$ could jump "above" $1$ or jump "below" 1. So the evaluation map that takes a quickly converging Cauchy sequence $(a_n)$ and produces $f(\lim a_n)$ will not be continuous. That is the real obstacle to a constructive proof of this result, assuming the reals are defined as Cauchy sequences.

Answer (score 0):

This is an existence and uniqueness proof. Let's first do the case of $x \geq 0$. Let $N_{x}=\{n \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}:x<n+1\}$ We know $N_{x}$ is non-empty because $\lceil x \rceil \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \leq \lceil x \rceil<\lceil x \rceil+1$ so $\lceil x \rceil+1 \in N_{x}.$ By the well ordering principle, we know $N_{x}$ contains a least element because $N_{x} \subseteq\mathbb{N}$. Let $m+1 \in N_{x}$ be the least element. Since $m+1 \in N_{x}$ we know $x<m+1$. Now for the sake of contradiction suppose $x<m$. Then $m \in N_{x}$ by definition of $N_{x}$. This is a contradiction, because $m<m+1$ yet we already have $\inf(N_x)=m+1$. So we conclude that $x$ is not less than $m$, or equivalently, $x \geq m$.

For uniqueness let's do contradiction again. Suppose there is some other $m'+1 \in N_{x}$ such that $m'\leq x <m'+1$. We already have $m+1$ as the least element of $N_{x}$ so $m'+1>m+1$. Further, as we are dealing with natural numbers we know $m+2 \leq m'+1$, as $m'+1$ must be at least one integer value larger than $m+1$. Clearly $x<m+2$ because $x<m+1$. We also have $m'\leq x$ and $m+1 \leq m'$ is obtained from $m+2 \leq m'+1$. It follows that $m+1<x$. This is a contradiction because we already know $m+1>x$. Thus, no such $m'+1$ can exist: $m+1$ is the unique element that works for our $x \geq 0$.

Now see if you can prove this for $x<0$.

Comment: This argument depends on the $\lceil \cdot  \rceil$ function, whose well-definedness is begging the question.

Comment: I can change that. Would modular arithmetic be begging the question?

Comment: Constructively, one cannot prove that, for every real $x$, either $x \geq 0$ or $x < 0$. So that proof by cases cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauhy sequence, we have for every rational $\epsilon >  0$ exists a integer $N \ge 1$ such that $| a_j - a_k| \le \epsilon$ for every $j, k \ge N$. Also we have $0 \le a_i - N_i < 1$ for all $i \ge 1$ (integer part for rationals).

Suppose we have a $\epsilon$ such that
$$\epsilon < a_j - N_j + \epsilon < 1$$
$$\epsilon < a_k - N_k + \epsilon < 1,$$
so
$$-1 < N_j - a_j - \epsilon < -\epsilon$$
$$\epsilon < a_k - N_k + \epsilon < 1$$
$$-\epsilon < a_j - a_k < \epsilon,$$
thus
$$-1 < N_j - N_k < 1 \qquad i.e. \qquad N_j = N_k.$$
Now we have $(N_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ *converge* to the same integer, and so this sequence is a Cauchy sequence equivalent to the integer desired.

To choose such $\epsilon$ we can use the minimal distance from $a_j - N_j, a_k - N_k$ to $1$ such that
$$\epsilon < \min (|1 - (a_j - N_j)|, |1 - (a_k - N_k)|).$$

For uniqueness, suppose that $N$ and $N'$ are two integer parts of $x$ real. Since
$$0 \le x - N < 1$$
$$0 \le x - N' < 1,$$
so
$$-1 < N - x \le 0$$
$$0 \le x - N' < 1.$$
Again, we have $|N - N'| < 1$. Thus $N = N'$.

Comment: I revisited the answer. Maybe, when one need to pick the $\epsilon < \min(|1−(a_j−N_j)|,|1−(a_k−N_k)|)$ the case "the real number $x$ is equivalent to a integer number" is not included. So that, it may be necessary to consider the cases: "when the real number is equivalent to integer and when it is not".

Comment: One cannot prove constructively that, for each real $x$, either $x$ is equal to an integer or it is not. So that proof by cases will not work.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to simply consider the set $$ A = \{ n \in \Bbb Z \ | \  n \le x \}  $$

By definition $A$ is bounded. Hence $ \sup A $ **exists**. And by "its" definition the Supremum of a bounded set of real numbers is **unique**. Now notice your $N = \sup A$ - the proof of which only requires the arguments:

$ N \gt x \implies N - 1 $ is an upper bound for $A$ which is absurd  $ \implies  N \le x $

$ N + 1 \le x \implies (N + 1 \in A) \; \land ( N + 1 \gt \sup A )$ which too is absurd $ \implies x \lt N + 1 $

Comment: We cannot prove constructively that every set of rationals has a supremum, much less every set of real numbers.